# Jenkins CLI list jobs returns empty file

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface

Attempting to export all jobs in our Jenkins to an Excel file.

Running the following command:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s URL:8080/ list-jobs > test.csv
```

Which saves a .csv file with nothing saved into it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming your `https://url:port` is correct, that command is valid. It works for me on Jenkins 2.90

Comment: If you have authentication configured, you might need `--username ${username} --password ${password}` or `-i ${private key}`, as described in the documentation. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI